# How do I get the business infowindow for a custom Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it. Here's an example of what I mean -> http://174.120.83.2/~highliac/location-burien-wa.php

Do I need to use the Places API as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google map api v3 you can use infobox. please check the link and try [Google Map api v3 - Infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html) . if any problem comes please comment me i will help you..

have a nice day